# FIxing MS Excel date time format

Tags: excel, csv

A reporting service generates a csv file and certain columns (oddly enough) have mixed date/time format , some rows contain datetime expressed as m/d/y, others as d.m.y

When applying =TYPE() it will either return 1 or 2 (Excel will recognize either a text or a number (the Excel timestamp))

How can I convert any kind of wrong date-time format into a "normal" format that can be used and ensure some consistency of data?

I am thinking of 2 solutions at this moment :

- i should somehow process the odd data with existing excel functions
- i should ask the report to be generated correctly from the very beginning and avoid this hassle in the first place

Thanks

Comment: you are on the right track! Try bullet point 2 first. If it fails, write a formula to convert the undesirable date formats! Excel has plenty of options for this.

Comment: If you open the CSV file in notepad, are the dates inconsistent, or is this happening when the file is opened in Excel? It may be that Excel is expecting dates in (eg) m/d/y but your file has dates in d/m/y.  Excel will convert what it can (when "d"<=12 it gets treated as a month) and leave the others as text.

Comment: Tim, I checked the csv using notepad and it contains rows in different formats , m/d/y and d.m.y , that is worrying me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly your second option is the way to go in the medium-to-long term. But if you need a solution now, and if you have access to a text editor that supports Perl-compatible regular expressions (like Notepad++, UltraEdit, EditPad Pro etc.), you can use the following regex:

```
(^|,)([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(?=,|$)
```

to search for all dates in the format `m/d/y`, surrounded by commas (or at the start/end of the line).

Replace that with

```
\1\3.\2.\4
```

and you'll get the dates in the format `d.m.y`.

Comment: both of your solutions are ok

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get the data changed then you may have to resort to another column that translates the dates: (assumes date you want to change is in A1)

```
=IF(ISERR(DATEVALUE(A1)),DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1,4))),VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,2)),VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1))),DATEVALUE(A1))
```

it tests to see if it can read the text as a date, if it fails, then it will chop up the string, and convert it to a date, else it will attempt to read the date directly. Either way, it should convert it to a date you can use

Comment: both of your solutions are ok but it's unfortunate that I can't accept two answers